# pipenv failed to build image pip

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I was trying to start a pipenv shell to start working on a django project on python 3.8.9 and it keeps giving me this error:

```
Using C:/Users/CY/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe (3.8.9) to create virtualenv...
[=== ] Creating virtual environment...RuntimeError: failed to build image pip because:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\cy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 57, in _install
installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
 File "c:\users\cy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 46, in install

for name, module in self._console_scripts.items():
File "c:\users\cy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 131, in _console_scripts
entry_points = self._dist_info / "entry_points.txt"
File "c:\users\cy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 118, in _dist_info
raise RuntimeError(msg)  # pragma: no cover
RuntimeError: no .dist-info at C:\Users\CY\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\wheel\3.8\image\1\CopyPipInstall\pip-21.1.1-py3-none-any, has pip
  
Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here at play, both having similar error messages. There's an issue where the Windows path become too long, with a reference [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1971): it simply requires enabling long paths on Windows.

Also, suddenly virtualenv broke unexpectedly, on Linux. I don't know why, but the fix was posted [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3683). It involves a fresh re-install of virtualenv.

You might simply try both methods. Note that deleting your local virtualenv settings may result in some loss of virtualenv configuration.

HTH